# Structure of Redis-Java Projects

Tags: redis

I just found out about Redis and i find the concept of key-value databases interesting.
I want to start using Redis but i don't quite understand how i would structure my project.

When i use mysql, its more like i have a backend written with Java/Python, clients make request to my web application and my Java/Python code gets information from the database and sends it to the clients or it also writes information from clients into the database.

I would like to know how Redis is structured so i can start building applications with it. I would also appreciate any sample projects/templates (Especially server side)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to start using Redis but i don't quite understand how i would
>   structure my project.

You should first start with defining the functionality of your project in order to figure out the requirements for the database structure.

> When i use mysql, its more like i have a backend written with
>   Java/Python, clients make request to my web application and my
>   Java/Python code gets information from the database and sends it to
>   the clients or it also writes information from clients into the
>   database.

Databases (especially redis which has very trivial authentication system) shouldn't be exposed directly to clients, so it's the backend part which is responsible for dealing with data - in your case Java or Python. I think this makes it identical or similar to what you are used to with MySQL.

> I would like to know how Redis is structured so i can start building
>   applications with it.

I would recommend to first read [fifteen minute introduction to redis data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) and some general [overview](http://redis.io/topics/data-types). Note however that redis doesn't support querying language like SQL which you might be used from relational database systems that could limit it's usefulness depending on your project needs.

Comment: Do i have to pre-construct my redis db like how it would be done in mysql such as write and run the sql commands to create tables and all that before being able to save to it?

Comment: @elimence No, since redis is an advanced K/V store you don't have to pre-construct the schema in the form of tables. You just directly perform operations which values will be stored into given keys.

Comment: To add to this, you should also look at a connection driver (akin to jdbc driver).One of the popular ones which we use at work is [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis).